# Command line SSIS (DTEXEC) with Proxy account

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I know we can start an SSIS package from DTExec.  And when we define an SSIS job in SQL Agent, I can change the Run As to be a pre-defined Proxy account.

Now, can I run an SSIS package from DTExec, using a Credential(Proxy) account, in a batch file?  I can't find anything in the documentation for that option, but thought I would ask.

Comment: You want to run an exe in a different security context. It depends how you are running it now. For example, if you are running it from windows scheduler you can specify the account it runs under. If you are running it interactively you can use `runas.exe`. If you are running it from SQL Agent using CmdExec step, you already have an option to use a proxy account.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, currently we are running through SQL Agent, and use the SQL Server Integration Services Package type, and Run as (proxy account).

I'm looking into bypassing SQL Agent and just running in batch files using DTExec.  This works until we need to use another account.

Comment: Well how will you run these batch files? Manually? Note that you can run batch files in SQLAgent and utilise the proxy.